# Basic jQuery slideDown() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Super simple question - I'm new to jQuery so I'm a little bit stupid with it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ve5f3oeb/

```
<a href="#" id="forgotten-show">I have forgotten my password ></a></div>

        <form class="forgotten-pw" action=""><!-- This still needs to dropdown from clicking the #forgotten-show link above -->
            <input type="email" placeholder="Your email"><!-- Prefill this field with their email address as they type just in case they have forgotten their email -->
            <div class="row inline-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Send password">
            </div>
            <p class="pw-reminder-sent">Your password has been sent</p>
        </form>

$("#forgotten-show").click(function() {
  $(".forgotten-pw").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

I have display: none; set on the form so I want to toggle slide up and down. Surely the jQuery is sound as I took it from the documentation. What am I missing?

UPDATE: OK my JSFIDDLE went tits up.

My issue is the code works when the jQuery is inside a script tag on the same page but not working from a linked JS file.

I know the file is linked properly because I have other things going on that work.

Comment: You’re missing jQuery =) For JSFiddle, you can select it in the JavaScript settings menu. https://jsfiddle.net/ve5f3oeb/1/

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p1eLrce4/

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have jQuery on my dev version and  it's still not working.

Comment: @lejimmie If jQuery *is* actually loaded, then execute the jQuery when the DOM loads.. wrap it with `$(document).ready(function () {...});`... if that fails, check the console for errors.

Comment: Ok so when I added the above code in a script tag on the page itself it worked. but no working form the js file it's linked too. Pathing is fine.

Comment: HI Josh. Tried that still didn't work. Checked console no errors. Did a console.log for when I click it and nothing came up. This is from an js file. However when putting the code on the page itself it works. Weird. JS file is definitely linked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you forgot to include the jQuery library?

Try

https://jsfiddle.net/ve5f3oeb/2/

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ve5f3oeb/3/